# Contact Form 7 shortcode is commented out, but I receive spam emails from it

Tags: shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a CF7 in one page, that actually isn’t working and I commented it out, so it does not appear on the site. But the interesting thing is that I receive spam emails from this form. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you commented it out using HTML comments WordPress still replaces the short code by a form which is just not visible to the visitor but it exists in your page source code

Comment: Ok, but how I can receive spam if the form actually is not working? It is configured correctly, but does not work, it refreshes after submit.

Comment: I don't know CF7 in detail so I can't answer this question. I just knew the part about shortcodes.